# python 3 pandas series indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pickle file which contain a pandas.serie, when i print the indexes of this serie i got " datetimeindex".
is it possible to print indexes like " 0 1 2 3 4 " insteed of " date time index " ? 
her's my code :
`with open(picklefile,'rb') as f:
        data=pickle.load(f)
        print(data["x"].index)`

the output i got is :

```
DatetimeIndex:(['2016-03-01 10:31:00', '2016-03-01 10:32:00',
               '2016-04-05 18:57:00', '2016-04-05 18:58:00',
               '2016-04-05 18:59:00', '2016-04-05 19:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=50910, freq='T')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `reset_index` method and do it inplace, without creating new object.

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

> inplace : boolean, default False Modify the Series in place (do not
>   create a new object)
>
> drop : boolean, default False Do not try to insert index into
>   dataframe columns

The inplace parameter affect the result only when `drop=True` and the result stays as series.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) if need unique monotonic index `0,1,2,...` and then new column from dates is created:

```
data = data.rename_axis('Dates').reset_index()
```

If need remove `Date`s:

```
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

EDIT:

Maybe also is possible use [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html):

```
data=read_pickle(f).reset_index()
print(data["x"].index)
```

Comment: use only first solution `data = data.rename_axis('Dates').reset_index()` and then if need column same as index values `df['new'] = df.index`